# js.erb not refreshing page rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to update a particular part of my page using ajax, but the js.erb file doesn't seem to be replacing the content in my div. I have also noticed that the locals are not being passed to my partial for some reason. In my controller, I have a show action that loads the show.html.erb and when an item is clicked it sends an ajax request. The items sit within a div with an id="stream-contents". The request is sent to an action in my controller named get_tree_folder and the response is formatted as JS. The js.erb and partial files sit in the same folder as my show.html.erb.

here is my controller action get_tree_foler:

```
def get_tree_folder
  @file_view = false;
  @curriculum = Curricula.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @git = get_bare_repo @curriculum
  @branch = params[:branch]
  tree = @git.gtree(params[:tree])
  @child_trees = tree.trees
  @child_blobs = tree.blobs

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

my js.erb file get_tree_folder.js.erb:

```
$('#stream-contents').html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'tree', :locals => { branch: @branch, child_trees: @child_trees, child_blobs: @child_blobs, curriculum: @curriculum }) %>);
```

the console output:

```
Started GET "/curricula/5/master/a9d280e6a0eb41ab7ea012f10f516913b2e53061" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-27 13:52:36 -0700
Processing by CurriculaController#get_tree_folder as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "branch"=>"master",        "tree"=>"a9d280e6a0eb41ab7ea012f10f516913b2e53061"}
Curricula Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `curriculas`.* FROM `curriculas` WHERE `curriculas`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
Rendered curricula/_tree.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered curricula/get_tree_folder.js.erb (2.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the parameter to `$('#stream-contents').html()` in quotes:

```
$('#stream-contents').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'tree', :locals => { branch: @branch, child_trees: @child_trees, child_blobs: @child_blobs, curriculum: @curriculum }) %>");
```

Comment: Why is it that you can't tell if the partial is rendering or not?  Can you add your partial `/app/views/curricula/_tree.html.erb` to your question?  Log shows the partial is rendered!  On `locals`, you can check the `local_assigns` hash which should contain all the passed `locals`.

Comment: I actually got it figured out. In my partial the link to was <% link_to %> and not <%= link_to %>. Thanks for the help though!